# Is there a word to describe being mentally fatigued?

Tags: adverbs

"I'm tired" or "I'm exhausted" usually convey physical fatigue (or are ambiguous between physical and mental fatigue). What I'm looking for is an efficient way of conveying mental fatigue.

Comment: "My brain is fried."

Comment: I dunno, I'm going brain dead on this one.

Comment: Thanks.  I think brainfried is probably the most exact way of conveying the state I'm trying to describe.  Brain dead comes in a close second...

Answer (score 3):

How about "burned out?" That's what I usually say.

Comment: Yes,  and I would say "burnt out" to make it even less formal.

Comment: But "burned out" has (at least in my environment) connotations above and beyond being fatigued: you might be fatigued after coding for 12 hours, whereas you would risk being burned out if you coded for 12 hours every day for 6 weeks. I think the usage converges for people who are mentally fatigued for a long period.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "frayed"?  I find "burned out" a bit informal.

Comment: To me, "frayed" carries the connotation of being stressed, not tired.

Answer (score -3):

**Doneski** (/dənˌskē/) [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Doneski), Slang, 6. being burnt out; done

Webster defines *done* as: (4) physically exhausted. Commonly, and in the Urban dictionary, *doneski* denotes a person who has overindulged. Although it's an adjective, it is the state of being mentally incapacitated.

---

[Polish Surnames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_name):

> the adjectival suffix -ski, -ski or -sky is found in many other Slavic languages... derived for example from a persons place of residence, birth or family origin.

[In Polish](http://www.polishroots.org/Research/SurnameSearch/Surnamesendings/tabid/118/Default.aspx):

> it's an adjectival suffix, meaning simply "of, from, connected with, pertaining to." The form X-ski is an all-purpose way of saying "somehow associated with X."

Comment: Yeah Urban Dictionary that excellent and reliable source

Comment: This is 'and Usage' not 'Learners'. @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: So? This is heavily localised slang; it's a stretch to say that "English Usage" covers this edge case. That's the problem with Urban Dictionary.

Comment: All bets are off when you ask for an 'efficient way of conveying' something. You knew exactly what I meant didn't you? Doneski is usually more biased to mental fatigue. @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: I have _never_ heard the term "doneski" before now. Never. I did _not_ know what you meant. It is highly localised slang (didn't I already say this? strange...). So, no, it's not an efficient way of conveying something. Typical American, your biases are making you assume that everybody uses your slang but in fact there's a large world out there.

Comment: Born and raised in Chicago with it's hefty Polish population, my assumption of the prolificacy of this slang word may be unfounded. @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: Would it add insult to injury if I told you that I'm half Polish?

Comment: Yes. I think it should for both of us. @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: I think it would have been more clear to me if the pronunciation was included (/dənˌskē/). When I originally saw the word, I was thinking /dōˌnəsˌkē/, to which I could not relate.